# Do I need to be Level 3 editor to send data to Waze using the Road Closure solution from Esri's ArcGIS Solutions for Local Government?

Tags: arcgis-local-government, waze

We are new to the Waze for Cities program. Currently, I am trying to get information regarding how to submit road closure data to Waze using [Road Closure](https://community.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsolutions.arcgis.com%2Flocal-government%2Fhelp%2Froad-closures) solution from Esri's ArcGIS Solutions for Local Government. I read all the documentation for this solution, as well as the guidelines provided by Waze for this task. Being an Esri shop, we want to use this tool rather than Waze Map Editor since WME will not work for our workflow.

Since we are new to the Waze for Cities program, we are Level 1
   Editor. Per Waze, we are required to be at leaves Level 3. Is that
   correct?

**See the *Closure feature permissions*:** https://wiki.waze.com/wiki/Real_time_closures#WME_closure_feature

Comment: Have you consulted either Waze or Esri on your questions (all 3 of them)? If so, what did they answer.

Comment: Yes, and have received no response so far. That is why I opted to try here after waiting for 8 days.

Comment: Have you made a follow-up call? Why did you not include this informations in your questions? Furthermore, what insight do you think this community can provide which the software provider can't?

Comment: Erik, I was not aware that I had to include all details, that is, that I have reached out the different vendors? Have you dealt with any of them?  Have you dealt with Waze support before? If so, maybe you can relate. I just posted the questions I have regarding my issue. I always do follow-up call but have not done it yet regarding this issue. I thought I can gain some time by asking in this forum in case someone has already implemented the solutions and have the answers for them.

Comment: Sometimes you can find that support centers from companies are not as efficient as you expect. Thus, I go I do my research myself and when I can’t find the solution, I ask people within the community to find out if someone has encountered these issues and has the answer for them.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this question...

**All CCP linked accounts show as rank L1 but allow permissions to do closures. L3 rank is only required if you are a non-partner editor.**